# Как найти количество слов в строке, которые состоят только из строчных латинских букв?

Tags: windows, c++, visual-studio

Новичок, пишу консольное приложение в visual-studio, никак не получается найти количество слов в строке, в которой должны считаться только слова из строчных латинских букв.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

Comment: печально :(

Comment: @Fairy, посмотрите в сторону регулярных выражений.

Comment: Разделите задачу на части:

1. Разделить строку на слова
2. Выяснить, состоит ли слово только из латинских букв
3. Подсчёт элементов коллекции, удовлетворяющих заданному условию.

Действуйте. Подробнее вам не напишут, потому что это тривиально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

//1-ый способ решение задачи
size_t n_words1(const char* s){
    const char* p;
    size_t i = 0;

    do {
        while(*s && ! isalpha(*s))
            ++s;

        for(p = s; (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z'); ++p);

        if((ptrdiff_t(p - s) > 0) && ! isalpha(*p))
            ++i;
        else {
            while(isalpha(*p))
                ++p;
        }
        s = p;

    } while(*s);
    return i;
}

//2-ой способ решение задачи
size_t n_words2(const char* s){
    const char* t = s;
    int  n, is;
    size_t i = 0;

    while(*s){
        n  = 0;
        sscanf(s, "%*[^a-z]%n", &n);
        s += n;
        is = ((t == s) || !isalpha(*(s - 1)));

        n  = 0;
        sscanf(s, "%*[a-z]%n", &n);

        is &= ! isalpha(*(s + n));
        if((n > 0) && is)
            ++i;
        s += n;
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void){
    cout << "cnt: " << n_words1("The bla, abc, ABC, Abc, bob") << endl;
    cout << "cnt: " << n_words2("The bla, abc, ABC, Abc, bob") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```